# How do I fix hard shifting gear selector on 1994 F-150 auto transmission?

Tags: wiring

I have replaced the neutral safety switch and the shift tube (broke due to difficult shifting). When a second person gets in and starts the truck, I can get under the truck with a socket wrench and very lightly move the trans lever while the second person moves the gear selector and it seems fairly easy to move. When it is just the driver trying to move the gear selector, it's almost impossible to shift into any gear without breaking the shift tube again. I followed the linkage cable and it seems to be not only in good condition, but looks like it's only a few years old.

Can anyone help me?

Also, is it possible that the linkage cable looks perfect on the housing, but could be getting stuck inside?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact this should have been flagged to migrate instead of closed. Would have been much more helpful to the OP... I've flagged it now, we'll see what happens.

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you. I forgot that I could Flag it. Instead I got annoyed as usual that the Close reason of "another site" only allows Meta DIY and not any other site - should allow selection of *any* site - Woodworking and Electrical Engineering are common targets but you never know when it might be something else like in this case.

Comment: Yup. Our list of "migrate" options is silly and basically shouldn't even exist for as little is as on it. File that suggestion under the heading of "Things we know but sometimes forget..." ;)

Comment: I took off the bushing connection of the linkage cable (from under the dash and from the transmission arm) last night, now the gear selector moves like it should. The cable still looks great, but is rather difficult to move back and forth by hand. Feeling like this is the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was the linkage cable. I removed it, tried moving the cable through the housing with my hands, and it was somewhat difficult. I got the new part and it moves completely effortlessly before installation. Installed it, and all ran perfectly again!